# Output sound to everyone

Tags: javascript, html

```
function play(){
          var audio = document.getElementById("sound");
          audio.play(); }

<button onclick="play()">Press</button>

<audio id="sound" src="123.mp3" ></audio>
```

What I want to do is to play sound for everyone who's currently on website. Is this possible? Which language or method should I search for?

PS. This is my second try to ask question correctly, hope I did it right this time.

Comment: Hi. For doing something like this you would need a server to connect to. For example WebSockets. This way you could tell the server, to broadcast a message to all the users of the site.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in the comments mentioned, you can go on with the socket principles. Basically for me the choice was `socket.io` in `nodejs`. With this I wrote a chat application. As you know it is almost the same pattern with your use case. I had to broadcast the messages to all the clients in the same chat group. Socket.io has also a client library, where you can listen to events. You can define your own event and broadcast them to clients which are listening to the event and the socket.

Good luck!